# dynamically created checkbox in c# using asp.net show vertically

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, vertical-alignment, contentplaceholder

I have created the `checkbox` dynamically in C# with inside the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`. I want that to be ordered in vertical and only one box will be checked at a time in code behind. Any solution?

Code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Betoption", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add("Main", "1");
table.Rows.Add("Corner", "2");
table.Rows.Add( "Card & Foul", "3");
table.Rows.Add( "Under / Over", "4");
table.Rows.Add( "Dilantin", "5");
table.Rows.Add( "Home / Away", "6");
table.Rows.Add("First Half", "7");

DataRow[] exemption = table.Select();

foreach (DataRow dr in exemption)
{
    string option = dr["Betoption"].ToString();
    string optionID = dr["id"].ToString();


    var chk = new CheckBox { ID = optionID, Text = option, CssClass = "name", AutoPostBack = true };

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(chk);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Checkbox` you can use `CheckBoxList` and set value of `RepeatDirection` Property as shown below:

```
var checkList = new CheckBoxList();
checkList.AutoPostBack = true;
checkList.CssClass = "name";
checkList.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Vertical;

foreach (DataRow dr in exemption)
{
    string option = dr["Betoption"].ToString();
    string optionID = dr["id"].ToString();

    checkList.Items.Add(new ListItem()
    {
        Text = option,
        Value = optionID
    });

}

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(checkList);
```

And if you want only one item to be checked at a time, I would suggest to use `RadioButtonList` instead of Checkbox list.

In above code, Just replace `CheckBoxList()` with `RadioButtonList()`

Comment: Not a corret ans,all checkbox will be checked,and not vertical alignment

Comment: @AamecAamec: When you set `RepeatDirection.Vertical` it will render all checkboxes vertically. If you want to render it horizontally you can change it to `checkList.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;`

Comment: ya correct but i want only one checkbox to allow check

Comment: @AamecAamec see my answer for RadioButtonList